# How we can auto remove standalone\tmp\vfs\temp from JBoss directory

Tags: java, jboss, server, jboss6.x

Whenever i start the `JBoss` on windows machine, it auto creates temporary folders in `standalone\tmp\vfs\temp` directory of `JBoss`. Eventually the size of temporary data becomes huge. it's tedious to manual delete it.  So need help if anybody has resolved this problem by removing temporary folders on shutdown event of `JBoss`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using JBoss 6.x as per the tags. Huge Logs generated under /vfs is most likely due to the -Xrs option of the JVM parameter.

There are no CLI commands available which prevent this or clear the logs during shut down. We can manually delete the files when the server is stopped or We can delete them during the startup as a temporary workaround.

Add  `rm -rf ../standalone/tmp` in the standalonde.sh/standalone.bat. This will clear the files while starting the server instance. But It is highly not recommended to clear the tmp dir when the server is running.

This issue was fixed in the version 6.4.0, It is good to upgrade it to the latest.

Comment: 'rm -rf ../standalone/tmp' it won't work for windows machine?